# autofac not resolve properly generic List type

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am trying to resolve list of object using autofac Container, and expecting an empty list in response. However, I am not able to get empty list in return instead getting count as 1.

I also try with without list registration in aotufac conatiner but getting same response.

```
<pre><code>
   class autofacFactory : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(List<>)).As(typeof(IList<>));
            builder.RegisterType<Response>().As<IResponse>();
            builder.RegisterType<CustomDependencyResolver>().As<ICustomDependencyResolver>();
        }
    }
    public class Response : IResponse
    {
        public string TransactionNo { get; set; }
        public string SchemeCode { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IResponse
    {
        string TransactionNo { get; set; }
        string SchemeCode { get; set; }
    }


    public interface ICustomDependencyResolver
    {
        TResolved Resolve<TResolved>();
    }

    internal class CustomDependencyResolver : ICustomDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

        public CustomDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        }

        public TResolved Resolve<TResolved>()
            => _lifetimeScope.Resolve<TResolved>();

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new autofacFactory());
            using (var container = builder.Build())
            {
                ICustomDependencyResolver customDependencyResolver = container.Resolve<ICustomDependencyResolver>();
                var collection = customDependencyResolver.Resolve<ICollection<IResponse>>();
                var list = customDependencyResolver.Resolve<IList<IResponse>>();
            }
        }



    Actual response:
        [Image1][1]
        [Image2][2]


        [Expected Response][3]


          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVXeW.jpg
          [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k58QX.jpg
          [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcFyc.jpg
```

Comment: Where is the code that resolves the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try not registering `IList<>` or `List<>` - [Autofac has built-in support for that](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b).

Comment: Its working fine when I remove List Registration and Response class registration from autofac then I am able to resolve IList<Response> with empty object. but in this case I am not able to resolve response class because I remove Response class from autofac registration.

Comment: Keep the other registrations. **Only** remove the one for lists.